# Please Help Identify This Old Window Lock

Tags: windows

[image: Top view]I have one Window lock broken. Attached is a picture of a good one for reference. It is on single-hung window. The house was built in 2007. Unfortunately, there isn't any window maker name on windows. I searched on Internet and cannot find any similar pictures. Asked a few local service persons. they didn't know either.

I really appreciate it if someone could ID what the lock name could be called or the manufacturer name. It will be great if some stores are selling this kind of lock.

Thanks!

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: Did you unscrew the latch and look inside for ID markings?

Comment: Hi , I haven't. I am afraid of making the thing worse by breaking another. But I will try. thanks!

Comment: @Aloysius Defenestrate. in US

Comment: Once you have the lock off, you can get dimensions and, likely, find a different style that will mount into those screw holes and still be able to push its deadbolt into the other window sash. You might have to clean the top of this sash, as the new lock may not be the same shape/size and may leave dirty/clean spots visible. You may also want to replace both locks, just so they match.

Answer (score 2):

That might be [this](https://www.swisco.com/sash-lock-keeper/pd/Hung_Sliding-Window-Replacement-Latches/90-323), or one of the "See also" products on that page, or if not there's a form on that site where you can mail them pictures of your hardware for identification.  It helps if you remove it and take careful measurements of the hole spacing ... between the holes and from the holes to the window edge.

I have no interest in that company other than being a repeat happy purchaser of obscure nameless window and door hardware for repairs in my old house.

Answer (score 1):

Unscrew the lock from the window and look for manufacturer markings on it. If you find some, see if you can get in touch with the manufacturer to buy a replacement.

If there are no markings or the manufacturer is out of business, you can get dimensions of the lock and, likely, find a different style that will mount into those screw holes and still be able to push its deadbolt into the other window sash.

You might have to clean the top of this sash, as the new lock may not be the same shape/size and may leave dirty/clean spots visible. You may also want to replace both locks, just so they match.